# About django macaddress

Tags: django

I want to get macaddress;
verification is performed can be identified (or individual PC) individuals who start the browser, 
I could not it is; please help me!

this is my views.py:

```
import commands
import struct
import uuid

def getmac(iface):
    ifconfig = commands.getoutput("ifconfig " + iface + "| grep HWaddr | awk '{ print $5 }'").strip() 

    if len(ifconfig) == 0:
        getmac = 'Mac not found'
    else:
        getmac = ifconfig[:17] 
    return getmac
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing server code capabilities with client side.

On server, you're running Python, Django, Apache/Nginx etc.

On the client side, you can assume only browser, perhaps with javascript and cookies capabilities. You can not assume Python support, any libraries or OS on client devices.

Another issue, client is connected through a set of network layers, and unless you are not in the same LAN it involves routing. Any packet from client to your server will get router's MAC address instead of client, so it is not possible to get client's MAC address from network communication either.

And finally, MAC address is malleable. It is possible to use fake MAC address, so if you were going to use it for authentication, it is not going to work.